# How can I check if push notifications were disabled in React Native using PushNotificationIOS?

Tags: react-native

I'd like to determine if push notifications were disabled by a user using React Native with PushNotificationIOS.

`PushNotificationIOS` has the method `checkPermissions`, but this method only tells me whether notifications are enabled.

I would like, using React Native, to tell if my app prompted the user to enable notifications and the user denied the permission, or if the user independently went to settings and disabled notifications.

In native code, you'd use `UNUserNotificationCenter` and check `getNotificationSettings` for `authorizationStatus` with value `.denied`.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you have any progress with this one?

Answer (score 4):

I can suggest to you try [this library](https://github.com/yonahforst/react-native-permissions). This library have all features that you mention above. For me it's work great, hope for you too.